# How to disable onWindowFocusChanged event in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, focus

Is there a possible way to disable onWindowFocusChanged in a fragment

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if(hasFocus) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you require to do that

Comment: I am capturing this event in my main activity, I want to disable it in some fragment

Comment: maybe remove `super` call?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve by doing this. You can't disable the method call because it's part of the Android framework, but you can certainly ignore it simply by not overriding it.

If you want to do something in the fragment in response to the window focus changing but only want to do it in certain activities, add a method to the fragment to achieve whatever you want to do and then call it from `onWindowFocusChanged` in the activity.

If I've misunderstood the intention of your question then please do let me know.

Comment: if he won't override this method it will be called anyway and do its job under `super` call (probably dispatching focus on any view, which Jihin Raju don't want to happen as far as I understood)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    //remove this line super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    //do nothing inside
}
```